# How solved cordova firebase plugin error?

Tags: android, firebase, cordova

How can I solved Firebase error in Cordova?

> Cordova Play Services Version Adapter' has detected an error. The following dependencies of 'Google Play Services' are not compatible:
>   You have an incompatibility of versions with the following dependencies of 'Google Play Services':
>
> - 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'
> - 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.+'
> - 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.+'

It doesn't exists a version of 'Google Play Services' that includes all these dependencies.
ll dependencies of 'Google Play Services' must have the same version.
The application may not compile.

Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-s
>   ervices plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bin
>   tray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the
>   version of com.google.android.gms to 10.+.

Comment: Please share your build.gradle file

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=13RjxKsbadfxTpvCexqHSCOIB1nABKRe4

Comment: project.ext {
      defaultBuildToolsVersion="27.0.1"

      defaultMinSdkVersion=19 //Integer - Minimum requirement is Android 4.4

      defaultTargetSdkVersion=27 //Integer - We ALWAYS target the latest by default

      defaultCompileSdkVersion=27 //Integer - We ALWAYS compile with the latest by default

    }

Comment: what version of google-service plugin are you using?

Comment: I dont know. I saw plugins folder and there is not google-service plugin.

Comment: do you have a platform folder inside of it there is android and ios folders?

Comment: There is cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated in platform/android

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191511/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-libaba-liyev).

Comment: I want add notification with firebase(with cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated plugin)